# Dynamically create part of JavaScript block in aspx page from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am integrating SagePay drop in form this requires a unique session key to be requested via SagePay API for each transaction. I have successfully got code to get the key (using code behind) as follows :-

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim myReq As HttpWebRequest
        Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse
        Dim myData As String = "{""vendorName"": ""myvendorname""}"
        Dim mySessionKey As String

        myReq = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://pi-live.sagepay.com/api/v1/merchant-session-keys")
        myReq.Method = "POST"
        myReq.ContentType = "application/json"
        myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("apikey:apipassword")))
        myReq.GetRequestStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData), 0, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myData).Count)

        myResp = myReq.GetResponse
        Dim myreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
        Dim myText As String
        myText = myreader.ReadToEnd
        'Response.Write(myText)
        mySessionKey = "{ merchantSessionKey: '" & Mid(myText, 65, 36) & "' }"

    End Sub
```

This results in producing the following string (mySessionKey) which is in the format required to finalise the transaction (the GUID is different each time):-

{ merchantSessionKey: 'F42164DA-4A10-4060-AD04-F6101821EFC3' }

The above needs to then be injected into the .aspx page in a javascript block as detailed below :-

```
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <h1>My Test Shop</h1>
      <form>
        <h2>Payment Details</h2>
        <div id="sp-container"></div>
        <div id="submit-container">
         <input type="submit"/>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      sagepayCheckout({ merchantSessionKey: 'F42164DA-4A10-4060-AD04-F6101821EFC3' }).form();
    </script>
  </body>
```

I am at a loss of how to dynamically inject this into the aspx page.

Any points, so gratefully received.

Comment: This link might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

Put it in your viewstate

ViewState("merchantSessionKey") = ....

Then in the code:

```
<script>
  sagepayCheckout(<%= ViewState("merchantSessionKey") %>).form();
</script>
```

Or if you make it a public variable on the page level (right now the variable is local to the method):

```
<script>
  sagepayCheckout(<%= mySessionKey %>).form();
</script>
```

Comment: I believe that viewstate will not work on mobile devices, so would prevent this working on say a phone making a payment from the web page. Also as the viewstate would be base64 encoded, would it not be a security concern, albeit that the session key duration is only 400 seconds...

Comment: you are putting it on the page in plain text anyway...so i dont know how its more of a security risk

Comment: you could do a public variable at a class level

Comment: Thanks guys, yes guess security is not such an issue, as it is only valid for that session with that vendor with those payment details, it is not exactly portable. Ctznkane525 you are right it is there in plain text in javascript. I will try these ideas when back in tomorrow. Some people were talking about using RegisterClientScriptBlock, but I admit i was totally lost on that...

Comment: OK so i used the viewstate and this I cant explain (these are expired keys now :-)) So Sagepay API responds with valid session key 41BBB9C4-9F7D-40A6-89E2-ABA6102C208E. When I right click and get page source it has in serted a different session key appears the correct format :- sagepayCheckout({ merchantSessionKey: '6BD30256-B5A4-4B1A-AC65-AB4448AF159D' }).form();. Any ideas ???

Comment: i assume you are going to get a different key each time...if you are doing post backs on this page at any point...you are calling the service each time you do a post back...in that case...store the data in the session and only do it when not a post back

Comment: So this is just is literally just running the single page project from VS2017 using iis express, I am writing the key to the screen in code behind then immediately right click the screen view source and the two keys are different. Wouldn't have thought any extra postbacks or page refresh was taking place??

Comment: What two keys do u mean though...there's only one variable

Comment: Sorry not making myself clear was rushing to catch a plane, so I have a response.write in my code behind that puts the key on my development page as soon as the request to the sagepay api completes. When the page has loaded if I view page source the key in the page source is different from the one that is on the screen from the original response.write. This is without any page refresh or any further post back.